# Windows Phone Pivot Control : hook swipe event

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'd like to have 2 pages for my Pivot control and when user swipe left or right, I'd like to do something but I can't find swipe event per se ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `SelectionChanged` event.

See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.selectionchanged) for details